# Error trying to get Arquillian working on jboss

Tags: jboss, jboss-arquillian

Have been trying to follow the following tutorial to get arquillian working on jboss:

http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/#generate_project_from_archetype

But currently getting the following error:

```
Tests in error:
  org.arquillian.example.GreeterTest: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
```

POM FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.arquillian.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>container-test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- <version.arquillian_core>1.0.0.CR5</version.arquillian_core> <jboss.version>7.1.0.Beta1</jboss.version> 
            <junit.version>4.8.1</junit.version> -->
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                                    <type>zip</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-integration</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.avh4.util</groupId>
            <artifactId>imagecomparison</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.advancestores.storechannel</groupId>
            <artifactId>epcfe-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.advancestores.storechannel</groupId>
            <artifactId>epcfe-data</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>20020423</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

ARQUILLIAN.XML:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="jbossas-managed" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">C:\appservers\jboss-eap-6.1\jboss-eap-6.1</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

EDIT FULL STACKTRACE:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.arquillian.example.GreeterTest
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.323 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  org.arquillian.example.GreeterTest: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.866s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 29 09:12:13 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/30M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) on project arquillian-tutorial: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\james.land\arquillian-tutorial\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: I think there is more info you can post about the error.  Please update question with full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Did you active Jboss related profile in your IDE? In pom.xml once you mentioned your profile you have to active the profile in project properties as shown [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/#test_across_containers) .

***Set active Maven profile: Manual configuration***

***To set the active profile manually, follow these steps:***

```
   Right click on the project(your project)and select Properties 

   Select the Maven properties tab

   Enter the profile id in the Active Maven Profiles field(e.g., arquillian-weld-ee-embedded)

   Click the OK button and accept the project changes
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.arquillian.example </groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <url>http://arquillian.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
</plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
<artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha6</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

</project>

**Don’t add unnecessary dependencies to the maven might cause version mismatch error.
This pom is sufficient enough to run Arquillian.**
```

Comment: Please describe your answer

Comment: 1)skip the test and run your program,or else add m2e plugins for Your IDE                                                                  2)use dependencies only which are required.